# SVG path getting stretched out

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG path which is the full width and height of the screen. When resizing the screen the width of the stroke is getting stretched out. I'm thinking this has something to do with the preserveAspectRatio attribute.

Is there anything to prevent the stroke from being stretched out?

HTML

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 659 522" enable-background="new 0 0 659 522" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path class="path" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M656.5,2.5v517H2.5V2.5H656.5z" stroke-dasharray="2042 300" stroke-dashoffset="2342" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
svg {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
.path {
    animation: dash 10s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccqxcnw0/1/)

Comment: There is an attribute but it is not supported by IE. Would that be fine?

Comment: Yeah I could look at it

Comment: Have a look at [this attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke).

Comment: I used the attribute but now there are 2 dashes instead of 1 in my stroke, I updated my jsfiddle

Comment: Hmm, yeah the non scaling stroke seems to be affecting it. I don't know why and maybe somebody who knows SVG better can clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### vector-effect: "non-scaling-stroke";

**Seems to do the trick**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}
.path {
  vector-effect: "non-scaling-stroke";
  stroke-width: 20px;
  animation: dash 10s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 659 522" enable-background="new 0 0 659 522" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path preserveAspectRatio="none" class="path" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M656.5,2.5v517H2.5V2.5H656.5z" stroke-dasharray="2042 300" stroke-dashoffset="2342" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>
```

Why is there a gap in the stroke?
stroke-dasharray="2042 300" <- because this creates gapes
stroke-dasharray="2042 300" how big do you want to gap to be?
The full shape?
stroke-dasharray="2042 2042" :p creates an illusion of a stroke "drawing" the shape.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}
.path {
  stroke-width: 20px;
  animation: dash 10s linear infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 659 522" enable-background="new 0 0 659 522" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path preserveAspectRatio="none" class="path" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#00ff00" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M656.5,2.5v517H2.5V2.5H656.5z" stroke-dasharray="2042 2042" stroke-dashoffset="2342" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you know why it gives 2 dashes in the stroke instead of 1?

Comment: It has to be one dash and it has to be moving constantly almost like the snake game like in my fiddle ;)

Comment: @AC3 unless you use javascript and change the value of the dash-array on a rezise event this will never work since the length of the array will change with the browser since we are saying it should not scale anymore.